# How to include the colorbar into the figure's width

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is likely to be a very common situation, but I haven't been able to find any solutions online. The colorbar from the figure in the left overlaps with the figure on the right

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {},
            xlabel = ,
            ylabel = ,
            view={0}{90},
            only marks,
            colorbar
            ]
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \label{fig:ContourPlot}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=\linewidth,
            title = {},
            axis lines = middle,
            ylabel near ticks,
            xlabel near ticks,
            xlabel = {},
            ylabel = {This Overlaps},
            ]
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \label{fig:LowestImmediate}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{(a) . (b) .}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Before writing an answer: do you insist on having `\label`s in the subfigures without `\caption`s? (I do not think that this makes too much sense, if that's what you want it would make IMHO more sense to put two `axis` objects in one `tikzpicture` and this one in the figure, all potential problems would be easily solved that way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main confusion is what the `width` of a plot does.

[image]

This basically tells you that the colorbar is not taken into account properly and you need to make room for it. Apart from that I think you need to add `\caption` commands to the subfigure, the more so since you add `\label`s. Here is a possible choice of parameters.

[image]

Note that, since the widths of the subfigure boxes differs, I took the width of the plots to be proportional to some fixed distance (like `\paperwidth`) since `\linewidth` will be different in the subfigure boxes.